# Error deploying JBoss EAP 5.1

Tags: jboss, jboss5.x, rhel5

I am trying to deploy JBoss EAP 5.1 on RHEL 5 and I've gone through all the documentation for the install, yet I am still seeing the following errors in the server.log file.  I am able to hit the web, admin, and JMX console, but these errors still appear and the JMX console is telling me that the messaging component is Unavailable.  Am I missing something here?

Relevant parts of my log (the errors) are listed below:

```
2010-12-01 08:21:51,885 ERROR [org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.AbstractKernelController] (main) Error installing to Configured: name=SecurityStore state=Configured
java.lang.Exception: Error calling callback PasswordRegistrationAdvice for target context SecurityStore
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractLifecycleCallbackItem.install(AbstractLifecycleCallbackItem.java:91)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.handleLifecycleCallbacks(AbstractController.java:1589)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.handleInstallLifecycleCallbacks(AbstractController.java:1554)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:947)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:988)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:778)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:543)
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.deployer.kernel.BeanMetaDataDeployer.deploy(BeanMetaDataDeployer.java:125)
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.deployer.kernel.BeanMetaDataDeployer.deploy(BeanMetaDataDeployer.java:52)
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62)
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:55)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1454)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1172)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1193)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1113)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1652)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:938)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:988)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:826)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:556)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:789)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:699)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.ProfileDeployAction.install(ProfileDeployAction.java:70)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileAction.install(AbstractProfileAction.java:53)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.install(AbstractProfileService.java:403)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1652)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:938)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:988)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:778)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:543)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.registerProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:308)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:256)
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:461)
    at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:221)
    at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:556)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jboss.security.integration.password.PasswordMaskManagement.ensureKeyStore(PasswordMaskManagement.java:297)
    at org.jboss.security.integration.password.PasswordMaskManagement.getPassword(PasswordMaskManagement.java:163)
    at org.jboss.security.integration.password.PasswordLifecycleCallback.install(PasswordLifecycleCallback.java:113)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:59)
    at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectMethodInfoImpl.invoke(ReflectMethodInfoImpl.java:150)
    at org.jboss.joinpoint.plugins.BasicMethodJoinPoint.dispatch(BasicMethodJoinPoint.java:66)
    at org.jboss.beans.info.plugins.AbstractBeanInfo.invoke(AbstractBeanInfo.java:300)
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.AbstractKernelControllerContext.invoke(AbstractKernelControllerContext.java:291)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractLifecycleCallbackItem.install(AbstractLifecycleCallbackItem.java:87)
    ... 42 more

2010-12-01 08:22:10,462 ERROR [org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap] (main) Failed to load profile: Summary of incomplete deployments (SEE PREVIOUS ERRORS FOR DETAILS):

DEPLOYMENTS MISSING DEPENDENCIES:
  Deployment "jboss.jca:name=JmsXA,service=ConnectionFactoryBinding" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.jca:name=JmsXA,service=TxCM" (should be in state "Create", but is actually in state "Configured")
  Deployment "jboss.jca:name=JmsXA,service=ManagedConnectionFactory" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.messaging:service=ServerPeer" (should be in state "Create", but is actually in state "Configured")
  Deployment "jboss.jca:name=JmsXA,service=ManagedConnectionPool" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.jca:name=JmsXA,service=ManagedConnectionFactory" (should be in state "Create", but is actually in state "Configured")
  Deployment "jboss.jca:name=JmsXA,service=TxCM" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.jca:name=JmsXA,service=ManagedConnectionPool" (should be in state "Create", but is actually in state "Configured")
  Deployment "jboss.messaging.connectionfactory:service=ClusterPullConnectionFactory" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.messaging:service=ServerPeer" (should be in state "Create", but is actually in state "Configured")
    Dependency "jboss.messaging:service=PostOffice" (should be in state "Create", but is actually in state "Configured")
    Dependency "jboss.messaging.connectionfactory:service=ClusteredConnectionFactory" (should be in state "Create", but is actually in state "Configured")
  Deployment "jboss.messaging.connectionfactory:service=ClusteredConnectionFactory" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.messaging:service=ServerPeer" (should be in state "Create", but is actually in state "Configured")
    Dependency "jboss.messaging:service=PostOffice" (should be in state "Create", but is actually in state "Configured")
  Deployment "jboss.messaging.connectionfactory:service=ConnectionFactory" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.messaging:service=PostOffice" (should be in state "Create", but is actually in state "Configured")
    Dependency "jboss.messaging:service=ServerPeer" (should be in state "Create", but is actually in state "Configured")
  Deployment "jboss.messaging.destination:name=DLQ,service=Queue" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.messaging:service=PostOffice" (should be in state "Create", but is actually in state "Configured")
    Dependency "jboss.messaging:service=ServerPeer" (should be in state "Create", but is actually in state "Configured")
  Deployment "jboss.messaging.destination:name=ExpiryQueue,service=Queue" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.messaging:service=ServerPeer" (should be in state "Create", but is actually in state "Configured")
    Dependency "jboss.messaging:service=PostOffice" (should be in state "Create", but is actually in state "Configured")
  Deployment "jboss.messaging:service=PostOffice" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.messaging:service=ServerPeer" (should be in state "Create", but is actually in state "Configured")
  Deployment "jboss.messaging:service=ServerPeer" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.messaging:service=SecurityStore" (should be in state "Create", but is actually in state "** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss.messaging:service=SecurityStore' **")
  Deployment "jboss.mq:service=DestinationManager" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.messaging:service=ServerPeer" (should be in state "Create", but is actually in state "Configured")

DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "SecurityStore" is in error due to the following reason(s): java.lang.NullPointerException
  Deployment "jboss.messaging:service=SecurityStore" is in error due to the following reason(s): ** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss.messaging:service=SecurityStore' **



2010-12-01 08:32:57,854 ERROR [org.jboss.messaging.util.ExceptionUtil] (http-192.168.1.70-8080-2) ServerPeer[0] getDestinations
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jboss.jms.server.ServerPeer.getDestinations(ServerPeer.java:949)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AttributeDispatcher.invoke(AttributeDispatcher.java:99)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanAttributeInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanAttributeInterceptor.java:197)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.PersistenceInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceInterceptor.java:76)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:90)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.getAttribute(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:362)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.getAttribute(MBeanServerImpl.java:565)
    at org.jboss.jmx.adaptor.control.Server.getMBeanAttributeResultInfo(Server.java:144)
    at org.apache.jsp.inspectMBean_jsp._jspService(inspectMBean_jsp.java:299)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:322)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:249)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:638)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:444)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:382)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:310)
    at org.jboss.jmx.adaptor.html.HtmlAdaptorServlet.inspectMBean(HtmlAdaptorServlet.java:227)
    at org.jboss.jmx.adaptor.html.HtmlAdaptorServlet.processRequest(HtmlAdaptorServlet.java:100)
    at org.jboss.jmx.adaptor.html.HtmlAdaptorServlet.doGet(HtmlAdaptorServlet.java:81)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:525)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:95)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:451)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
2010-12-01 08:33:18,466 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/jmx-console].[HtmlAdaptor]] (http-192.168.1.70-8080-2) Servlet.service() for servlet HtmlAdaptor threw exception
javax.management.MalformedObjectNameException: Key properties cannot be empty
    at javax.management.ObjectName.construct(ObjectName.java:467)
    at javax.management.ObjectName.<init>(ObjectName.java:1403)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.propertyeditor.ObjectNameEditor.getValue(ObjectNameEditor.java:49)
    at org.jboss.util.propertyeditor.PropertyEditors.convertValue(PropertyEditors.java:265)
    at org.jboss.jmx.adaptor.control.Server.setAttributes(Server.java:190)
    at org.jboss.jmx.adaptor.html.HtmlAdaptorServlet$5.run(HtmlAdaptorServlet.java:403)
    at org.jboss.jmx.adaptor.html.HtmlAdaptorServlet$5.run(HtmlAdaptorServlet.java:400)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.jboss.jmx.adaptor.html.HtmlAdaptorServlet.setAttributes(HtmlAdaptorServlet.java:399)
    at org.jboss.jmx.adaptor.html.HtmlAdaptorServlet.updateAttributes(HtmlAdaptorServlet.java:259)
    at org.jboss.jmx.adaptor.html.HtmlAdaptorServlet.processRequest(HtmlAdaptorServlet.java:102)
    at org.jboss.jmx.adaptor.html.HtmlAdaptorServlet.doPost(HtmlAdaptorServlet.java:86)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:525)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:95)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:451)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Comment: Do you have any applications deployed? Which configuration are you using?